# sudo apt-get update fails public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY, sudo gpg --keyserver pgpkeys.mit.edu --recv-key also fails on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, 20.04, updates

While executing sudo apt update command getting below error:

```
**W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 4EB27DB2A3B88B8B**
```

I tried multiple solutions available but nothing worked. I tried below solutions.

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 4EB27DB2A3B88B8B
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 4EB27DB2A3B88B8B
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver-options http-proxy=http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb:80/      --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 4EB27DB2A3B88B8B
```

Please suggest how it can be resolved or what I am missing. Is there any other configuration needed??